# Convert row (rename) in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime

i use `LoadingRow` event, i need:

if value row in 4 column = `01.01.0001 0:00:00` then rename to `No payment`, else set default value...

```
DataRowView item = e.Row.Item as DataRowView;
DataRow row = item.Row;
var time = row[4];
if (Convert.ToString(time) == "01.01.0001 0:00:00")
{
   row[4] = "No payment";
}
```

but type for row[4] - is `DateTime`, and i have error, because **dont converting datetime to string**, please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the *type* of column but you can add an *extra* column of *string* type to the *DataTable*. Alternatively you can try [LINQ to DataSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb688086.aspx).